# How to change checkbox position on listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I want to change the position of a checkbox item in ListView.

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(com.inomera.sanalmarket.main.R.id.listView1);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked , ShoppingListDataManager.getInstance().shoppingNotes);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Its my listview code.
How can i reach simple_list_item_checked item and change position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your own Adapter and then do it.. refer this http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Answer (score 0):

Define your own layout instead of using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked`

You can find the original file in the sdk folder at

android-sdk\platforms\android-X\data\res\layout

where X is some number 1-13

Comment: @NTC's answer.  Implementing your own adapter will not move the checkbox if you still use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked ... You need to define your own layout for the listitem! Save yourself the hassle of implementing the adapter yourself and just change the layout